# R - count occurences of specific characters per row for certain columns and store result in new column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count

I have a data frame

```
Var1 <- c("Hnt_Pri_Pri_Sec_Sup", "Hnt_Sup_Sup_Sec_Sec", "Hnt_Pri_Sec_Pri_Sup")
Var2 <- c("LiG_Pri_Sec_Sec_Sup", "LiG_Sec_Sup_Pri_Sup", "LiG_Pri_Pri_Pri_Pri")
Var3 <- c("Nam_Pri_Pri_Sec_Pri", "Nam_Sec_Sec_Sup_Pri", "Nam_Sup_Pri_Pri_Sec")
df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3)

> df
                 Var1                Var2                Var3
1 Hnt_Pri_Pri_Sec_Sup LiG_Pri_Sec_Sec_Sup Nam_Pri_Pri_Sec_Pri
2 Hnt_Sup_Sup_Sec_Sec LiG_Sec_Sup_Pri_Sup Nam_Sec_Sec_Sup_Pri
3 Hnt_Pri_Sec_Pri_Sup LiG_Pri_Pri_Pri_Pri Nam_Sup_Pri_Pri_Sec
```

in which I would like to count per row the number of times the characters "Pri" occur and store the result in an additional column, such that:

```
> df
                 Var1                Var2                Var3 pri_count
1 Hnt_Pri_Pri_Sec_Sup LiG_Pri_Sec_Sec_Sup Nam_Pri_Pri_Sec_Pri         6
2 Hnt_Sup_Sup_Sec_Sec LiG_Sec_Sup_Pri_Sup Nam_Sec_Sec_Sup_Pri         2
3 Hnt_Pri_Sec_Pri_Sup LiG_Pri_Pri_Pri_Pri Nam_Sup_Pri_Pri_Sec         8
```

If I were to do the same operation with "Sec", it should return:

```
> df
                 Var1                Var2                Var3 pri_count sec_count
1 Hnt_Pri_Pri_Sec_Sup LiG_Pri_Sec_Sec_Sup Nam_Pri_Pri_Sec_Pri         6         4
2 Hnt_Sup_Sup_Sec_Sec LiG_Sec_Sup_Pri_Sup Nam_Sec_Sec_Sup_Pri         2         5
3 Hnt_Pri_Sec_Pri_Sup LiG_Pri_Pri_Pri_Pri Nam_Sup_Pri_Pri_Sec         8         2
```

I tried different usages of str_count but could not make it work. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(
    pri_count = rowSums(across(starts_with("Var"), ~ str_count(.x, "Pri"))), 
    sec_count = rowSums(across(starts_with("Var"), ~ str_count(.x, "Sec")))
  )

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Var1                Var2                Var3                pri_count sec_count
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Hnt_Pri_Pri_Sec_Sup LiG_Pri_Sec_Sec_Sup Nam_Pri_Pri_Sec_Pri         6         4
2 Hnt_Sup_Sup_Sec_Sec LiG_Sec_Sup_Pri_Sup Nam_Sec_Sec_Sup_Pri         2         5
3 Hnt_Pri_Sec_Pri_Sup LiG_Pri_Pri_Pri_Pri Nam_Sup_Pri_Pri_Sec         8         2
```